# Expected token got id error

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a JavaScript tag, from the ckeditor API in one of my HTML pages, that I use in a flask app.

In my layouts.html page I have this code:

```
 <....>
 <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.1/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace('editor')</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And then in my request_project.html I'm calling the API

```
{% extends 'layouts.html' %}

{% block body %}

<h1>Request a project </h1>
{% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="form-group">
    {{ render_field(form.title, class_="form-control") }}
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ render_field(form.description, class_="form-control" id="editor") }}
 </div>
  <p><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Then when I run the project I got a TemplateSyntaError saying
: expected token ',', got 'id'

How can this be?

Comment: the error message is actually telling you to put a comma before the `id=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
{{ render_field(form.description, class_="form-control" id="editor") }}
```

you are missing `,`

```
{{ render_field(form.description, class_="form-control", id="editor") }}
```